# How to pull a private container from AWS ECR to a local cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I am currently having trouble trying to pull my remote docker image hosted via AWS ECR. I am getting this error when running a deployment

Step 1)

run

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region cn-north-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn
```

Step 2)

run `kubectl create -f backend.yaml`

from here the following happens:

```
➜  backend git:(kubernetes-fresh) ✗ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-89d75f7df-qwqdq   0/1     Pending            0          2s

➜  backend git:(kubernetes-fresh) ✗ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
backend-89d75f7df-qwqdq   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4s

➜  backend git:(kubernetes-fresh) ✗ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-89d75f7df-qwqdq   0/1     ErrImagePull       0          6s

➜  backend git:(kubernetes-fresh) ✗ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-89d75f7df-qwqdq   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          7s
```

So then I run `kubectl describe pod backend` and it will output:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  117s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/backend-89d75f7df-qwqdq to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    32s (x4 over 114s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/baopals:latest"
  Warning  Failed     31s (x4 over 114s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/baopals:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/v2/baopals/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
  Warning  Failed     31s (x4 over 114s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     19s (x6 over 113s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    4s (x7 over 113s)   kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/baopals:latest"
```

the main error being `no basic auth credentials`

Now what I am confused about is that I can push images to my ECR fine and I can also push to my remote EKS cluster I feel like essentially the only thing I cant do right now is pull from my private repository that is hosted on ECR.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here that is preventing me from pulling from private repos so i can use them on my local machine?

Comment: have you created s image pull secret with credentials?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Did you do this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: I thought this would rely only for docker and not ECR though right? or is it the same thing

Comment: this is true for any private registry

Comment: is this not the same command for it?

`aws ecr get-login-password --region cn-north-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn` this is what allows me to push at least just not pull

Answer (score 3):

For fetching ECR image locally you have login to ECR and fetch docker image. while if you are on Kubernetes you have to use `secret` for storing ECR login details and use it each time for pulling image from ECR.

here shell script if you are on Kubernetes, it will automatically take values from AWS configuration or else you can update variables at starting of script.

```
ACCOUNT=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text) #aws account number
REGION=ap-south-1                                     #aws ECR region
SECRET_NAME=${REGION}-ecr-registry                    #secret_name
EMAIL=abc@xyz.com                                     #can be anything

TOKEN=`aws ecr --region=$REGION get-authorization-token --output text --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2`

kubectl delete secret --ignore-not-found $SECRET_NAME
kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
 --docker-server=https://$ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com \
 --docker-username=AWS \
 --docker-password="${TOKEN}" \
 --docker-email="${EMAIL}"
```

`imagePullSecret` used in YAML file for pulling storing secret for private docker repos.

https://github.com/harsh4870/ECR-Token-automation/blob/master/aws-token.sh

Answer (score 1):

When a node in your cluster launches a container, it needs the credentials to access the private registry to pull the image. Even if you have authenticated in your local machine, the node cannot reuse the login, because by design it could be running on another machine; so you have to provide the credentials in the pod template. Follow this guide to do that:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Basically you store the ECR credentials as a secret and provide it in the   `imagePullSecret` of the container spec. The pod will then be able to to pull the image everytime.

If you are developing with your cluster running on local machine, you don't even need to do that. You can have the pod reuse the image that you have downloaded to your local cache by either setting the `imagePullPolicy` under container spec to `IfNotPresent`, or using a specific tag instead of `latest` for your image.

Comment: ok thanks for the link i think this is making more sense now however from that doc I'm unsure of what this error is saying as i don't know what file it is trying to get

`kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=</home/noobskie/.docker/config.json> --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`

I run that but then get the error  `no such file or directory: --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`

I do have the first config it talks about

Comment: @NooBskie You need to remove the <> brackets if that's the cause.
Or try this approach as documented there, might be easier your first time

`kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>`

Answer (score 0):

For fetching ECR image locally or from any other kubernetes cluster like gke.
firstly setup aws-cli and configure the credentials.

ACCOUNT=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text)

REGION=ap-south-1

SECRET_NAME=${REGION}-ecr-secrets

EMAIL=abc@xyz.com

TOKEN=$(aws ecr --region=$REGION get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2)

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
 --docker-server=https://$ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com \
 --docker-username=AWS \
 --docker-password="${TOKEN}" \
 --docker-email="${EMAIL}"
```

And add imagepullsecrets in the deployment file with same level container

```
imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ap-south-1-ecr-secrets
```